# Wrong behavior SwipeRefreshLayout with CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, swiperefreshlayout

In my application, I need an appbar: a simple `toolbar` (always), a `layout` or a widget (when scrolling it should collapse), `tabLayout` (always).

This problem occurs with a `50%` chance of re-creating the view.

Without a `swipeRefreshLayout`, this problem is not present.

Please help to solve this problem. How best to achieve the desired result?

**Good Behavior**

[image: Good behavior]

**Wrong behavior**

[image: Wrong behavior]

**parent_fragment.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_toolbar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:elevation="0dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorAccent">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/app_name"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textSize="24sp" />
                    </FrameLayout>

                </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffffff"
                    app:tabTextColor="#afffffff" />

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <ru.kgdev.ecohelper.ui.widget.NoScrollViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**child_fragment.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/swipe"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
            </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trouble in `parent_fragment.xml`, in my opinion, right way: need wrap `AppBarLayout` with `TabLayout` and `ViewPager` in `LinearLayout` for avoid use `layout_marginTop` in the `ViewPager`. The result is the following `parent_fragment.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_toolbar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:elevation="0dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/app_name"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="24sp" />
                </FrameLayout>
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffffff"
                    app:tabTextColor="#afffffff" />

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <ru.kgdev.ecohelper.ui.widget.NoScrollViewPager
                android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

After this fix, my app work fine.
If anyone can explain the origin of this strange behavior in more detail, I will be grateful. Thank you.